# How do I check file permissions with stat?

Tags: python, file-permissions

There are several questions that talk about checking permissions using Python's stat module, but none of them are very clear about the results or how to interpret them.

The stat module has several useful looking constants:

- `stat.S_IRUSR`
- `stat.S_IWUSR`
- `stat.S_IXUSR`

And the same ones for `GRP` and `OTH`. However it's not clear how to interpret these results. I did find that you could use `stat.S_IMODE` to just clip the permissions bits but I'm still confused:

```
import pathlib
import stat
import tempfile


with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile() as f:
    p = pathlib.Path(f.name)
    print(oct(stat.S_IMODE(p.stat().st_mode)))
    p.chmod(
        stat.S_IRUSR | stat.S_IWUSR | stat.S_IXUSR
        | stat.S_IRGRP | stat.S_IWGRP | stat.S_IXGRP
        | stat.S_IROTH | stat.S_IWOTH | stat.S_IXOTH
    )
    print(oct(stat.S_IMODE(p.stat().st_mode)))


    print(oct(stat.S_IMODE(p.stat().st_mode) & stat.S_IRUSR))
    print(oct(stat.S_IMODE(p.stat().st_mode) & stat.S_IROTH))
    print(oct(stat.S_IMODE(p.stat().st_mode) | stat.S_IROTH))
```

With `&` it's just printing out the permission bit, and with | it's just printing out the permissions of the file?

If I wanted to have something like:

```
>>> print('User can read file?', can_user_read(file))
True
```

I'm aware that `os.access` exists, but if I want to avoid the possible security concerns and just use `stat`, what would I need to do?

Comment: What are the security concerns you're referring to? I'd argue that `os.access()` is generally going to give you a more reliable result than `stat()`; operating systems often have extensions allowing more fine-grained permissions that aren't reflected in the stat data; indeed, some such extensions are standardized (see POSIX ACLs).

Comment: ...if you're referring to TOCTOU issues, you get those just as much by checking `stat()` data; it's not a defense in any meaningful way -- the only right thing is to take a try-it-and-see approach to permission checking, treating an access-denied error on the actual attempt in the same way you would otherwise treat a check failure prior to same. `stat()` is strictly *worse* than `access()`; it still has the drawbacks, but gives you less-accurate data to start from.

Comment: In my case I don't care if *I* can access (I already do), I'm trying to make sure that other people can access the file(s).

Answer (score 1):

This is actually simpler that it looks. It can be confusing when you're just checking permissions that are already on the file - that's what bitwise and does: shows you which bits are set on both files.

If you simply want a boolean out of that, it's convenient because with Python treats 0 as False, and the rest of the integers as True. We also don't even need to bother with the `stat.S_IMODE` function, we can simply use our bitmask. It doesn't matter that there's irrelevant information:

```
  1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1  # 077 permissions
& 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0  # see bin(stat.S_IROTH)
---------------------------------
  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
```

By using `&`, we only care about what's in *both*.

That, plus the Truthy nature of integers means the requested function just looks like this:

```
def can_user_read(file):
    return bool(file.stat().st_mode & stat.S_IRUSR)
```